# С помощью какой программы можно открыть .sketch файл на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics, design

У меня Ubuntu 14.04. В интернете все говорят про **Avocode**.

Установил, пытался открыть скетч на что я получил ответ о том что мне нужно установить дополнительный плагин. Но на я сайте обнаружил что есть только плагин для Mac OSX.

Может кто либо знает как открыть файл с разрешением `.sketch` ?

Comment: 1. а что про него говорит программа `file`? (`$ file файл.с.суффиксом.scetch`). 2. какой программой он создан (или: откуда вы его взяли)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 2:  вероятно, это [SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/ru)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, значит, автору сюда: http://help.ubuntu.ru/fullcircle/35/sketchup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

возможно, этот файл создан программой [sketchup](http://www.sketchup.com/ru). значит, её и надо использовать для просмотра/редактирования этого файла.

проблема в том, что программа эта проприетарная, а сборки есть только для [*windows/api*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

но есть и хорошие новости: более или менее устойчиво *windows/api* можно эмулировать с помощью программы [*wine*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine) (имеется в репозиториях всех популярных дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux*). также полезным в данном случае будет пакет *winetricks* (также имеется в репозиториях). для актуальных версий дистрибутива *ubuntu*:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install wine winetricks
```

а после этого попробуйте запустить скачанный установщик программы *sketchup* с помощью программы *wine*:

```
$ wine SketchUpMake-ru-x64.exe
```

---

инструкция: http://help.ubuntu.ru/fullcircle/35/sketchup